# Extracting gettext translations from PHP heredoc syntax?

Tags: php, gettext, heredoc

I'm using PHP's gettext functions for doing localization. I'm using Poedit to do the actual translation, and with its "Update from sources" feature it is really easy to extract all the strings that need to be translated - except from inside heredoc syntax.

Poedit is using the xgettext program to generate the .po files from the PHP source files. And it works beautifully when the PHP code looks like this:

```
echo "<h1>". _("test") ."</h1>";
```

But the following doesn't get extracted (notice that a pseudo t-object needs to be used):

```
echo <<<EOD
<h1>{$->_('test')}
EOD;
```

In PHP code you could workaround the problem in the following way:

```
<?php
$t = _('test');
echo <<<EOD
<h1>$t</h1>
EOD
?>
```

But I really would prefer that the xgettext program could extract the string from inside the heredoc block.

A [workaround for that has been suggested](http://docs.php.net/manual/zh/ref.gettext.php#81646) in the PHP documentation comments. The workaround is to treat tell the xgettext program to treat the PHP source files as Python code. But using this approach in Poedit gives me a lot of syntax errors from the xgettext parser.

Does anyone know a workaround for getting xgettext to extract the translations from PHP heredoc syntax?

A somewhat related ticket has been opened on gettext project's ticket system: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?27740 This indicates that support for the heredoc syntax could be improved?

Comment: I created a ticket specifically for this: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?35944 I hope no more purists come to give workarounds. It's just annoying this is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

I am the reporter of the gettext ticket you're refering to in your post.
When I submitted the ticket, I had something completely different in mind, something more along those lines:

```
<?php
  $msg = _(<<<TXT
  He said: "Hello world!".
  TXT
);
?>
```

Gettext can not extract text from such heredoc/nowdoc strings, but this could be really useful when translating large pieces of text.

In my case, I use gettext in a CLI PHP script to translate chunks of texts that contain XML markup. That markup is part of the original text and has to be translated too. Having to manually escape each and every quote or apostrophe in the markup makes the messages quite hard to read in POedit or any other editor.

In your case, it seems you'd like interpolated code in (heredoc/nowdoc) strings to be extracted. You can easily workaround this problem by preparing the text before you actually use interpolation:

```
<?php
$t = _('test');
echo <<<EOD
<h1>$t</h1>
EOD
?>
```

I don't think this should be considered a bug because the exact equivalent to the code you posted using heredoc syntax would be:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>{$t->_('test')}</h1>";
?>
```

from which gettext can not extract the "test" message either.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Ups - apparently I didn't read the gettext ticket thoroughly enough. Because what I want is - kind of - the opposite: remove the markup from extracted strings in Poedit.

I was heading in the direction you suggest; with preparing the text outside before the interpolation. But I still see this as a workaround, it would be really useful to extract text from inside heredoc syntax (IMHO).

Comment: "You can easily workaround" Uhh, if one is using heredoc (like me) the content is huge! This is a bug-feature. It should be fixed.

Comment: Note that in PHP 7.3 with heredoc not aligned at the start of the line, the following `_()` after the heredoc block won't get extracted by `xgettext` (I think it may be a bug in gettext).

Answer (score 0):

Being a gettext proponent for years, it's hard not to notice this ticket is 13 years old now, and seems like gettext project does not see the situation as a bug or somehow critical.

The problem in itself is `xgettext` extractor does not treat heredoc/nowdoc php syntax as valid, and especially it's indented variation available since 7.3.

To continue using gettext workflow and POedit in particular, we developed a library that allows to handle translation extraction (via POT files), available at https://github.com/vertilia/text or as a composer requirement:

```bash
composer require vertilia/text
```

This may help other developers stay on gettext road.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of vertilia/text.

Comment: $translation = <<<EOT
    This is a translation string.
EOT;
$pattern = '/<<<EOT\n(.*?)\nEOT;/s';
preg_match_all($pattern, $phpCode, $matches);
Here, $phpCode is a string containing your PHP code, and $matches is an array that will store the matched translation strings.